# Can two servers with distinct content share one subdomain?

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, seo, dns, subdomain

My problem:
Server 1: An IIS box with a bunch of applications in production, all running on 'www.mydomain.com'

Server 2: A Linux/Apache box that will host my website's non-transactional pages.

I would like Server 2's content to be available from 'www.mydomain.com' - separate filenames and directories as those being used by server 1, but the exact same subdomain.

I don't believe this is possible using simple mod rewrite or .htaccess.

Is there some way to achieve this using Application Request Routing in IIS or proxypass in Apache?  Is there some way to have the 404 handler on Server 1 try to modrewrite to Server 2 seemlessly so that the client only ever receives an HTTP 200? (I don't want to kill my SEO here).

As for naming conflicts, Server 1 will only ever use a very limited set of subdirectories.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, could easily handle this with AAR or mod_proxy on both sides. Perhaps a better idea would be to front both boxes with a proxy, opens up alot more flexibility and solves many of those url rewriting issues you are looking at.